# Getting window maximization to work properly with Tint2

Tags: unity, window-manager

I've added a bottom taskbar to Unity with `tint2`.  Now I have the taskbar on the bottom of my screen as desired, but when I maximize windows their bottom edge sits under the taskbar that tint2 created.

How do I tell Unity that the bottom X pixels are off-limits?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open tint2 conf file:

```
gedit ~/.config/tint2/tint2rc
```

Find the #Panel section and ensure to set these variables as follow:

```
panel_dock = 0
panel_layer = bottom
```

Find the # Panel Authoide section and set:

```
strut_policy = follow_size
```

Find more useful hints [here](http://code.google.com/p/tint2/wiki/Configure)

Comment: That worked well, with one modification.  I left `panel_layer = top` as I had previously set, because I wanted non-maximized windows to still be over-written by the menu bar on the bottom.  Thanks!

Comment: Tint2 GUI is available now